# Как локализировать devise в rails приложении?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет, у меня есть небольшое приложение на Rails и я использую gem devise. Я не могу понять, как русифицировать гем. Я создал в `config/locales` `devise.ru.yml`, залил туда русифицированные сообщения, что скачал, но как установить `devise.ru.yml` вместо `devise.en.yml` не могу понять.
И ещё один вопрос: как изменить названия полей, к примеру, в формах входа, регистрации и тд. Я нашёл HTML-код, где смог изменить с "Log in" на "Вход", а как поменять названия полей (к примеру email, password) и checkbox "Remember me" так и не понял. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Обычно он не "вместо", а "вместе". Локаль на русский уже переключили?

Comment: @D-side не переключил. С полями разобрался, а с локализацией нет

Comment: Окей, самое время [начать](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#optional-custom-i18n-configuration-setup).

Comment: @D-side спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле **`config/application.rb`**:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
config.i18n.locale = :ru
```

Ну и, конечно, **`config/locales/devise.ru.yml`** должен начинаться с

```
ru:
  devise:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Использование готового гема [с имеющимися русскими переводами](https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n/blob/master/rails/locales/ru.yml) может оказаться проще.

```
gem 'devise-i18n'
```

Не забудьте перезапустить приложение.
Обязательно укажите локаль приложения как отписали выше

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
```

Comment: Не до конца прочитал вопрос. Чтобы русифицировать формы можно воспользоваться гемом 'rails_layout' и создать виды для device. Там можно будет руками исправить все поля. Но это один из вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! :)