# Локализация devise в ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, devise

[Как локализировать devise в rails приложении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450337/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-devise-%d0%b2-rails-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/820649?noredirect=1#comment1305742_820649)
у меня почему то при добавлении

```
В файле config/application.rb:

config.i18n.default_locale = :ru config.i18n.locale = :ru
```

Крашится при старте сервера с такой ошибкой

```
config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

> application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AirPikachu
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
config.i18n.default_locale = :ru 
config.i18n.locale = :ru
```

Comment: Вы же эти два конфига написали в две разных строки, а не так, как в вопросе?

Comment: Да в две разные строки

Comment: А выложите весь код application.rb в вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: @Василиса добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config должен быть внутри класса Application

```
module AirPikachu
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.   
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru 
    config.i18n.locale = :ru
  end
end
```